# ImportError: No module named pyodbc while deploying flask app with mod_wsgi on httpd

Tags: apache, anaconda, python-3.6, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I see this in error log while I'm trying to deploy a flask app with mod_wsgi on httpd server. Strange observation being I don't face this error with anaconda 2 version but anaconda 3 seems to have a problem. It works perfectly fine with anaconda 2 setup but fails with above error just by changing the version of anaconda.

WSGI config in httpd config file is as follows:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<VirtualHost *>

WSGIDaemonProcess example python-path=/tmp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/example/example.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/html/example>
    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help please? I checked if pyodbc is available or not with pip freeze and it shows 4.0.23 version. I see that it's not able to get its location somehow

EDIT:

```
ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc9beb5000)
    libpython3.6m.so.1.0 => /tmp/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 (0x00007f7ff217b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7ff1f5f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7ff1b92000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7ff198e000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f7ff178b000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7ff1583000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7ff1281000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7ff28fc000)
```

Comment: How are you changing the Anaconda version? You can't simply change the path to ``python-path``. The mod_wsgi module would need to be recompiled against the different Python version. You also shouldn't use ``python-path`` to set up the location of the virtual environment, use ``python-home``. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: I'm installing mod_wsgi from yum. And It's only with this lib that I'm facing this issue.

Comment: If you are installing from yum, then it is likely Python 2 and not even Anaconda Python. As mentioned in the virtual environment doc linked, you can't mix mod_wsgi compiled for one Python installation/version with a virtual environment from another. You will need to uninstall yum mod_wsgi and compile mod_wsgi from source code for Anaconda Python. See ``pip install`` method in https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/

Comment: Ok I followed instructions on the mentioned page and I face this error now `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so into server: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I've added python shared lib path `/tmp/anaconda3/lib/` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` also and I was able to see this upon running `ldconfig -p` too. But idk still what's going wrong

Comment: Why are you installing Anaconda under ``/tmp``? Anyway, you want to add ``LoadFile /tmp/anaconda3/lib/ibpython3.6m.so.1.0`` just before the ``LoadModule`` line for ``wsgi_module`` in this case. Chances are this will break after a while as some systems have a cron job which will remove old files under ``/tmp``, so you may find the Python installation later removed. You should never install stuff under ``/tmp`` if you want to keep it.

Comment: True. This is just for testing purposes that I've placed it under `/tmp` which is definitely not a long term solution. Now, the error is guess what `httpd: Syntax error on line 55 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /tmp/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 into server: /tmp/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` . 
Btw, I've removed the python shared lib path from `/etc/ld.so.conf` as it was interfering with other yum installations

Comment: Did you look in ``/tmp/anaconda3/lib`` to see what the actual shared library was called. That was only my guess. Do note that if you are on CentOS/RHEL and SELinux is enabled in some way, you may be prevented from loading shared libraries from ``/tmp`` anyway, which may be why it can't be found.

Comment: Yes. This `/tmp/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 ` exists. And, I've set `SELINUX=disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config` file too. Guess now the last hopeful thing to do is compiling mod_wsgi from source instead of pip?

Comment: Just don't put Anaconda in ``/tmp``. Compiling from source rather than ``pip`` is likely going to make no difference.

Comment: Wow. All those errors disappeared but even after including `LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"` and the corresponding `LoadFile /opt/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0` as indicated above, the wsgi_module doesn't get loaded into httpd (`httpd -M`) nor it throws any error upon starting the server. Strange.

Comment: But is Apache running? BTW, is that your only virtual host. Normally you would use ``VirtualHost *:80>``, not ``<VirtualHost *>``. You are also missing ``ServerName`` in it, so if not the only virtual host, your requests likely would go to the default virtual host.

Comment: Done. Solved my problem. I had some permissions issue after that point. Thank a lot for helping me out here. Saved my day.